# Converting time from (mm:ss.ddd) to (ss.ddd)

Tags: python, string, delimiter

I currently have a list of strings in the format (mm:ss.ddd):

```
[['0:00.762', '0:01.435'], ['2:01.374', '2:07.423'], ['3:01.412', '3:07.314']]
```

That I'd like to convert to strings in the format (ss.ddd):

```
[['0.762', '1.435'], ['121.374', '127.423'], ['181.412', '187.314']]
```

Essentially taking the characters to the left of the delimiter ':', converting to an integer, multiplying by 60, and adding it to the numbers to the right of ':' but before '.'

I am very unfamiliar with Python's string manipulation tools and was wondering if anyone can think of a clever and efficient way to do this using built in methods.

Thanks for all help

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to do it with string methods.  Better would be to parse it with `strptime` in built-in `datetime` module, then print it out again with `strftime`

Comment: @wim can `strftime` format `mm:ss` to `ssss`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break the problem down into parts. First, we need a function that can convert each element from the mm:ss.dd format to ss.dd. That's pretty easy to do:

```
def convert(s):
    mins, secs = s.split(':')
    mins = int(mins)
    secs = float(secs)
    secs = 60 * mins + secs
    return secs
```

It seems we can just use `map` to convert the elements of the list:

```
converted_times = map(convert, orig_times)
```

However, `convert` takes a single element (e.g., `'0:00.762'`), whereas the data is actually a list of lists -- specifically, a list of pairs. We need another function that accepts a pair of elements (as a list) and returns them. We also want to return them as a string rather than a float:

```
def convert_pair(p):
    p0, p1 = convert(p[0]), convert(p[1])
    return [str(p0), str(p1)]
```

Putting this together, we can simply do

```
converted_times = map(convert_pair, orig_times)
```

to transform the list of data pairs.

A sample of this code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/mdippery/10163960).

Answer (score 0):

```
from decimal import Decimal

times = [['0:00.762', '0:01.435'], ['2:01.374', '2:07.423'], ['3:01.412', '3:07.314']]

converted_times = [ [str(int(time.split(":")[0])*60 + Decimal(time.split(":")[1])) for time in time_list] for time_list in times]
# thanks @shaktimaan
```

But why are you doing this with string methods? Here's a better way:

```
import datetime

times = [['0:00.762', '0:01.435'], ['2:01.374', '2:07.423'], ['3:01.412', '3:07.314']]

def convert_time(times):
    for timepair in times:
        accumulator = list()
        for time in timepair:
            t = datetime.datetime.strptime(time,"%M:%S.%f")
            accumulator.append("{}.{}".format(t.minute*60+t.second,t.microsecond//1000))
        yield accumulator

for timepair in convert_time(times):
    print(timepair) # or whatever.
```

Comment: They come in as strings from a text file. They will be floats soon enough.

Comment: @AdamSmith This will

`converted_times = [[str(int(time.split(":")[0])*60 + Decimal(time.split(":")[1])) for time in sub_times] for sub_times in times]`

Comment: @AdamSmith Also, I would use a different variable name for the one using `time` :)